# How does cURL work in live server or web development?

Tags: api, curl, shopify

can someone here explain to me how does [cURL](https://curl.se/) works in web development? I'm integrating a 3rd party tool to a Shopify website and found the documentation of it that says I can authenticate the API token using **cURL** but I don't know how does this **cURL** really works, read a bunch of articles and documentation, saw some youtube video about it but it still go thru my thick skull.

As of my understanding **cURL** is a CLI tool? and then what? how does that work in the live server? like this code below, where should I put it on in the live server? if It is a CLI tool then what to do in the live server? or am I going to the wrong direction? I hope I;m making sense

```
curl -X GET 'https://sample.com/sample?api_token=123123' -H 'accept: application/json'
```

Comment: cURL is a client for many application layer protocols, mostly used on the command line. In your case, you can think of cURL like a web browser, which is just an HTTP/web client. All web clients connect to a web server, send a request, wait for a response, and optionally close the connection.

Comment: The Shopify documentation is walking you through an example of authenticating to Shopify using cURL. In a production environment, you'd likely make HTTP requests through other means built into your language, framework, or library. Again, they're just showing you an example. They are not stipulating that you must use cURL to use their API.